# Regular expression matching all text without part

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write regular expression which will match all lines ending with: `XYZ` except lines which ending with `AAXYZ`.

Some examples:

1. `ABCXYZ` - should be matched
2. `AAXYZ` - should NOT be matched
3. `ABXYZ` - should be matched

I started with following expression `.*[^A][^A]XYZ$` but it does not work for example 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] lines=Regex.Split(input,"[\r\n]+")
                    .Where(x=>Regex.IsMatch(x,"^(?=.*(?<!AA)XYZ$).*$"))
                    .Select(x=>x.Value)
                    .ToArray();
```

---

If you need only regex

```
^(?=.*(?<!AA)XYZ$).*$
```

Comment: I need regular expression, because I cannot use anything else than regular expression

Comment: Can I extend this expression to except also AABXYZ ? So B letter is optional?

Answer (score 1):

A regex seems like overkill here:

```
var matches = myInput.Split(new[] {'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                     .Where(x => x.EndsWith("XYZ") && !x.EndsWith("AAXYZ"))
                     .ToList();
```

---

If you *need* a regex, you could do something like:

```
^(|.|.*[^A].|.+[^A])XYZ$
```

This simply expands all the possibilities in a pipe-deliminated alternation:

- Simply `XYZ`
- Any single character followed by `XYZ` (e.g. `AXYZ`)
- Zero or more characters followed by a non-A and one more character then `XYZ` (e.g. `QAXYZ`, `foobarBAXYZ`)
- One or more characters followed by a non-A and `XYZ` (e.g. `XBXYZ`, `foobarXYZ`)